# Typescript avoid duplicate type for nullable value in Intersection

Tags: typescript

I built an array of objects with this type

```
export type MyDto = { prods: {id:string} | null } & {name: string};
```

than I filter it to get rid of null type so I've got this type

```
export type MyFilteredDto = { prods: {id:string} } & {name: string};
```

is there a way to avoid duplication (not using an other type) using for instance an utility type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type to specify that a property of a type is nullable:

```
type WithNullableProp<T, K extends keyof T> = T | {
  [k in K]: T[K] | null;
}

type MyFilteredDto = { prods: {id:string} } & {name: string};
type MyDto = WithNullableProp<MyFilteredDto, 'prods'>;

const test: MyDto = {
  prods: null,
  name: '1',
}

const test2: MyDto = {
  prods: { id: 'a'},
  name: '2'
}

const test3: MyFilteredDto = {
  prods: null, // type error
  name: '3',
}
```

The `WithNullableType` prop basically just says that a given property on an object is nullable.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3&ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgOQK4Bt0EMBG6IAKATgPZgA8AKgDRQDSUEAHsBAHYAmAzlANYQgSAMyiUAfFAC8oqAB8oAbwBQUKAG1eUOG3oBdAFyi1dXXKhsM6ANxKAvkqWhIUALIgAYnHSsiEDgBFgEilFKDBSbkMFOA59LmAibQBzWyhUgDJFNiwAWwhDeMS2FJsnaDdA4Ol4JDRMXHxiMnI3T28IXwCg2gBycJJuHrEbJQBjEjZ4qFZ4wwqgkOVVfsjzS2oVc1z8qB6ARh6N+zGJqZngACY5kErFzZWuKK1Y3awe2w3VbLzDHoueuwOcaTYDTCDxADM1zaPj8t2kSzCEUea0wtAA9OjpuBoB1SERNt8dj0IYc7EA)

Answer (score 1):

As a start you could use `Omit` and just ad the field as not nullable again. As shown in an other answer you can of course create your own utility type to handle this problem.

```
type DTO = { a: string | null, b: string }
type FilterdDTO = Omit<DTO, 'a'> & { a: string };

const test = [] as DTO[];

function isFilterdDTO(dto: DTO): dto is FilterdDTO {
    return dto.a !== null;
}

const filtered = test.filter(isFilterdDTO);

filtered.forEach(({ a, b }) => {
    a // var a: string
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgKgeSgXigbygQwFxQM7ABOAlgHYDmUAPlKQK4A2DANFAEa4EkVQC%20AUKEhQAYsQbAIhACbwkqBAFtiwADxzWAckyaAfFABk6LJyJlKvANz9%20AYwD2pAlEnPUAbQC6WPLERfrfgAzOlJbYGJHKGI8MQkpWUQACmlge1w5AEpcVPto3zjJGTl0fihyqEIIYDpCUihcgDpMKABCZFR6JmsBO0dnIPEiiGkUFwgCRsH4wiSYwoSswOnh6Sn7QgBRTFsACySkjExWNj5MlH00MoqWgHpbqAA3TEITfDMKfl5M-iA://)

Answer (score 0):

The code given by @OliverRadini might be incorrect because it allows the type to contain only the union. Which means you could have no `name` property in the example. It would be preferrable to do an intersection as such

```
type WithNullableProp<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> &
  {
    [k in K]: T[K] | null;
  };


type MyFilteredDto = { prods: {id:string} } & {name: string};
type MyDto = WithNullableProp<MyFilteredDto, 'prods'>;

const test: MyDto = {
  prods: null,
  name: '1',
}

const test2: MyDto = {
  prods: { id: 'a'},
  name: '2'
}

const test3: MyFilteredDto = {
  prods: null, // type error
  name: '3',
}

const test3: MyFilteredDto = {
  prods: null, // type error
  name: '3',
}

const test4: MyDto = { // type error, missing name
  prods: null,
}
```